# Error trying to change text on menustrip

Tags: c#

I have a form where the user enters a text and everywhere in MenuStrip that have that text will be changed. The method iterates through all the items, but is not making the change.
This is my code:

```
private void ChangeMenu(string oldtext, string newtext)
{
    frmMenu fmenu = new frmMenu();
    MenuStrip menu = fmenu.menuStrip1;
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menu.Items)
    {
        foreach (ToolStripItem subitem in item.DropDownItems)
        {
            if (subitem is ToolStripSeparator)
                continue;
            else
            {
                if (subitem.Text.IndexOf(oldtext) >= 0)
                    subitem.Text.Replace(oldtext, newtext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could not find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because the `String.Replace` method returns a new string with the corresponding replacement(s).
Replace the `else` part with the following code:

```
if (subitem.Text.Contains(oldtext))
    subitem.Text = subitem.Text.Replace(oldtext, newtext);
```

Comment: I removed the procedure of an exclusive class for my methods and put in the main menu and it worked. Thanks anyway